# Access violation error with the new command

Tags: c++, access-violation, new-operator

I am working on an assignment for my GUI programming class, in which we are to make a windows program that displays the contents of a file in hexadecimal. I have a class that holds the text and creates the hex in string format.

I'm attempting to create an array of character arrays to store each line for output. However, when I use *new* to create the array of character pointers, I get an access violation error.

I've done some searching, but haven't had any luck finding the answer.

The class has these member variables:

```
char* fileText;   
char** Lines;
int numChars;  
int numLines;  
bool fileCopied;
```

My constructor:

```
Text::Text(char* fileName){  //load and copy file.
   fileText = NULL;
   Lines = NULL;
   fileCopied = ExtractText(fileName);
   if ( fileCopied ) {
      CreateHex();
   }//endif
}//end constructor
```

ExtractText loads the file given to the constructor, and copies it into a large string.

```
bool Text::ExtractText(char fileName[]){
   char buffer = '/0';    //buffer for text transfer
   numChars = 0;              //initialize numLines
   ifstream fin( fileName, ios::in|ios::out );  //load file stream
   if ( !fin ) {     //return false if the file fails to load
      return false;
   }//endif

   while ( !fin.eof() ) {      //count the lines in the file
      fin.get(buffer);
      numChars++;
   }//endwh

   fileText = new char[numLines];  //create an array of strings, one for each line in the file.

   fin.clear();           //clear the eof flag
   fin.seekg(0, ios::beg); //move the get pointer back to the start of the file.

   for ( int i = 0; i < numChars; i++ ) { //copy the text from the file into the string array.
      fin.get(fileText[i]);
   }//endfr
   fileText[numChars-1] = '\0';
   fin.close();
   numLines = (numChars % 16 == 0) ? (numChars/16) : (numChars/16 + 1);
   return true;
}//end fun ExtractText
```

Then comes the problem code. In the CreateHex function, the first line is where  try to create the array of character pointers.

```
void Text::CreateHex(){
    Lines = new char*[numLines];
```

As soon as the program runs that line of code, that's when I get the access violation. I'm not really sure what the problem is, because I've used that exact same method before in a previous program. The only difference was the name of pointer. I'm using Borland C++ 5.02 if that makes any difference. It's not my first choice in compilers, but its what our teacher wants us to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute the line

```
fileText = new char[numLines]
```

The variable numLines has not yet been initialized. As a member variable, it's initialized to 0, so you are allocating an empty array for fileText.

Comment: NumLines is set at the end of ExtractText to the number of 16 character lines in the file.

Comment: Indeed, but that is after it has been used!

Comment: CreateHex is only run AFTER ExtractText completes. numLines is set to a positive, non-zero value at the end of ExtractText. Look at the constructor. ExtractText runs, and if it returns true, then CreateHex runs. If ExtractText returns true, then numLines has to have at least a value of 1, except maybe if I tried to load a blank file, but that is not the issue that I'm having. I can assure you, and I've verified it by debugging, that numLines has a positive, non-zero value when it is used.

Comment: I meant the use of numLines about halfway through function ExtractText, not the one in CreateHex.

Comment: I complete overlooked that one, because that section of code was executing with no issues. This is some reused code, and the array in ExtractText is supposed to use numChars. However, I think that is, in fact, what was causing the access violation, because when I changed that, CreateHex runs with no errors. I guess that just goes to show that the line that throws the error isn't always the culprit.

Comment: That is what makes debugging so "fun."